# How to pass async Task with parameters as a method argument?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, task

I have the following code but am getting the following errors
[image]

The first at line 21 is

> "Delegate 'Func' does not take 2 arguments"

The second at line 28 is

> "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'"

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

```
// Online C# Editor for free
// Write, Edit and Run your C# code using C# Online Compiler

using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics; 

public class HelloWorld
{
    async Task Print1(string a, string b)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Printing!");
    }
    
    async Task PrintLoop(Func<Task> printer, int iterations = 3)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            string c = "1";
            await printer(c, c);
        }
    }
    
    async Task Main()
    {
        string a ="";
        string b = "";
        await PrintLoop(Print1(a,b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of your parameter `printer` in `PrintLoop()` needs to have the type of `Func<string, string, Task>` as your `Print1()` method has two Parameters of type `string` and a return value of type `Task`.

Have a look at the [overload `Func<T1, T2, TResult>` in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=net-7.0).

Also, you need to pass the delegate, not call it. Here's a working example:

```cs
    public class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a = "";
            string b = "";
            await PrintLoop(Print1);
        }

        async static Task Print1(string a, string b)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Printing!");
        }

        async static Task PrintLoop(Func<string, string, Task> printer, int iterations = 3)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                string c = "1";
                await printer(c, c);
            }
        }
    }
```

BTW: as of now you do not use any asynchronous calls therefore there is no point in using `Task`s. You also do not use the parameters supplied to `Print1()`.

Comment: You should mark your method `async` if you want to use `await`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but still, there's no point using `await` or marking methods as `async` if you're not doing something that is actually asynchronous, which OP is not here.

Comment: I don not agree, in this case you see the code of `Print1`, but if you are not able to see it, how would you know if it does use async? You are not checking the IsCompleted property or more important, where would you catch any exceptions thrown by the method. Async methods gives some overhead, but sometimes you need to handle exceptions where you need to. In this case calling it inside a loop.. ps: You example doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the parameters of the `PrintLoop` then you have to do the following:

```
async Task PrintLoop(Func<Task> printer, int iterations = 3)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        await printer();
    }
}
```

- The `Func<Task>` means it is a function without parameters that returns an awaitable `Task`

```
async Task Main()
{
   string a ="";
   string b = "";
   await PrintLoop(() => Print1(a,b));
}
```

- If you want to pass `Print1` with parameters then you have to pass it by wrapping that into an anonymous method (lambda expression)